# How to tell what module has called the program

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

When using [Dynamics] [AX] is there a system function that can be used
to determine which module the user was in when the program was called?
  I want to execute different X++ lookup code for employee, 
for the ProjJournalTable form, but this would
be a different employee-list depending on which module is calling
the form.  Hope that's clear!   - Maeve

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. It is possible to check what form/class the form/class you're currently in has been called from. It is also possible to check a record from what table has been passed as an argument to the form or class you're currently in. Is it something that can help you?

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of "module" in the execution context of a form or report. Therefore there is no system function to return that.

How to get around context dependant behaviour, where the behaviour depends on the caller?

The usual method in say a lookup form is to inspect `element.args()` for one of:

- `element.args().dataset()` and/or `element.args().record()`
- `element.args().parmEnumType()` and `element.args().parmEnum()`
- `element.args().parm()`
- `element.args().caller()`
- `element.args().parmObject()`

Take a look on the form `LedgerAccountLookup` for example, you can find many more by searching for "args" in form methods named "init".

Comment: Is there a way to pass a variable on the menuitem that calls the form?  That would be a way to tell, if there were different menu items if/when the form was called from a different menu-hierarchy.  I see there is a "parameters" properties for a menuitem. How can I check the value of this parameter when the form is called?  That could solve my problem.  Thanks for your help! - Maeve

Comment: The `parameters` property is read by `element.args().parm()`. Also there are properties on the menuitem which is read by `element.args().parmEnumType()` and `element.args().parmEnum()`